# How to solve clone git error in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, egit, eclipse-mars

I installed eclipse mars into my mac computer. When I try to import from my bitbucket git repository, I get an error shown below:

[image]

Egit error log is below

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.8.0_66
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=tr_TR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/*****/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/Users/*****/Documents/WS/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/*****/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

org.eclipse.egit.ui
Error
Sat Nov 07 23:36:34 EET 2015
https://******@bitbucket.org/*****/*****.git: authentication not supported

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://******@bitbucket.org/*****/*****.git: authentication not supported
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://******@bitbucket.org/*****/*****.git: authentication not supported
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:202)
    ... 4 more
```

I continued my works by cloning from git using sourcetree and importing project from my local directory.

Why this error occurs?

Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried at the git command line?

Comment: Check the Error Log view to see if there's an actual error message you can try to decipher.

Comment: I edited my  question. I cloned repo by sourcetree without any problem @JonahGraham.

Comment: I added error log to my post @nitind.

Comment: Putting your username and password into the Remote's URL directly isn't supported. You should be prompted for them through the UI when needed. Change the URL to be https://bitbucket.org/whatever.

Comment: I tried by changing url as u mentioned. it does not work. It was working on earlier eclipse versions with egit plugin. I think there is a bug in this version @nitind.